# Load theme from existing chart

Tags: r, mschart, officer

Using [`officeR`](https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/) and [`mschart`](https://ardata-fr.github.io/mschart/) packages I'm trying to match the theme of the company presentation. Is there a way to obtain the chart theme (for a further use in `mschart`) from an existing chart in `pptx`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `officer` does not implement such a function. 
However, you can get the color of the theme with function `color_sheme()` and reuse them with `mschart`:

```
x <- read_pptx()
color_scheme ( x = x )
```